# Scheduing an event in android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I have to schedule an event in Android. My event is starting a service and just doing the work in background even when the application is not running.

Can I do this even without Broadcast Receiver?

For starting the service, do I need Broadcast Receiver?

I saw some posts, only some of them used Broadcast Receiver :

[How to start Service using Alarm Manager in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321443/how-to-start-service-using-alarm-manager-in-android) 
[Scheduling an event in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471321/scheduling-an-event-in-android) 
http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html 
http://justcallmebrian.com/2010/04/27/using-alarmmanager-to-schedule-activities-on-android/

**UPDATE:**

From the posts that I read further, I realize that I have to use Broadcast Receiver if the app is not running at the time of event, but I don't need Broadcast Receiver if my application is running at the time of event. Please let me know if I have reached the right conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) to achieve your requirements .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I want the event to occur at a particular time. So, I think my requirement would facilitate the use of Alarm Manager